# An error occurred during project running after HUAWEI DTM is integrated and compiled

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

What should I do if "AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token)." is displayed during project running after DTM is integrated and compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the encoding format to UTF-8 by adding -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the gradle.properties file of your project.